# How to add quick edit and bulk edit fields to users admin section

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-meta

Salutations, is there a way to add quick edit and bulk edit fields for the users section in wordpress. I have found a lot about post types and custom post types but i'm specifically looking to add ability to edit custom meta fields i have added to the users.

Comment: I use Advanced Custom Fields for nearly every custom meta fiels. It's super easy and you can put your fields whereever you want ! http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ =)

Comment: Have you had a look at this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta-manager/

Comment: I was looking for a pluginless way to go about this, don't want my plugin to be dependent on others